# Difference between 2 projections?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, coordinate-system, mapnik

I have osm.xml file where projection is defined as follows:
Map background-color="grey" srs="&srs900913;" minimum-version="2.0.0">

n settings.xml file projection is also set there as:

```
<!ENTITY osm2pgsql_projection "&srs900913;">
```

I want to know what is the difference between these 2 projection. I have changed osm2pgsql projection to wgs-84 and it runs f9 for some files. i am confused in this thing

---

**EDIT**

When i use srs4326 projection i am getting error on console which is as follow: Unknown projection string, using web mercator as never the less. +init=epsg:4326

I have long/lat coordinates i want to use srs4326 projection

Comment: First projection is not a projection, but an entity. I guess it denotes EPSG:3857, tile projection. You skipped the second projection definition. For minimizing hassle, I'd recommend installing [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and adding your PostGIS layer there: you can specify the projection there with a drop-down box.

Comment: edited check second one

Comment: Try changing osm2pgsql_projection to `&srs4326;` or `&srsmercator;`. Between those two projections in your question there is obviously no difference.

Comment: sir both these projections are giving error of unknown projection string

Comment: See `entities.xml.inc` for a list of available entities / projections.

Comment: All of above three projections are listed there

Answer (score 1):

`entities.xml.inc` lists the possible projections supported by Mapnik:

```
<!ENTITY srs900913 "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs +over">
<!ENTITY srsmercator "+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +over">
<!ENTITY srs4326 "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0">
```

Note that srs900913 is defined on a sphere (EPSG:3857), while srsmercator uses the WGS84 ellipsoid (that's hidden behind +datum=WGS84) usually known as EPSG:3395. Both have a shift of about 20 kilometer unless you are near the aequator. The last one uses lat/lon degree coordinates (EPSG:4326).

Which parameter you have to use depends on the way you stored the data with osm2pgsql. The first one is the default, while the others requires an import with the -M or -l option. But to be honest, I have never seen tiles with those projections, and I am not sure if the style and generate_tile.py files work with that.

In `settings.xml.inc` you define the entity:

```
<!ENTITY osm2pgsql_projection "&srs900913;">
```

which is used inside osm.xml, unless you use the parameter directly:

```
<Map background-color="#b5d0d0" srs="&srs900913;" minimum-version="2.0.0">
```

Comment: thks for reply, i want to use srs4326 as i have long/lat coordinates which i have converted to geometry from st_geomfromtext(). but i am getting an error of unknown projection string

Comment: You could convert them to EPSG:900913 inside Postgis before rendering. Do you get an error message stating at which module and line the error occured? It would be good to include that in your question. You can still edit it.

Comment: In your other question, you have `srs="&srs900913;"` for the Map and `srs="&osm2pgsql_projection;"` for the layer. This might go wrong if both are not the same.

Comment: sir you have written in your answer that i have to import with -M or-l option if i have to use srs4326 projection?

Comment: question edited

Comment: You have the option, yes, but style file and generate_tiles.py might have to be changed too. The -M is for srsMercator, not epsg4326. What about your Map object?

Comment: sir its not rendering using srs4326, tiles are also not generated, but wit srs 900913 it is rendering and tiles are also generated but it is not showing projection as i have long/lat coordinates

Comment: As written above, reproject the points to EPSG:900913 inside your Postgis database before rendering, and it will work.

Comment: i have data in regions column as ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))

Comment: how to reproject these points to ESPG:900913?

Comment: http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html